# Xcode 15 Can't remove User-Defined rows in project settings

Tags: ios, xcode

Before Xcode 15.0, I removed this rows. After updating it appeared again without possibility to remove it. In this screenshot part of my settings.

[image]

When I'm trying to rename it, it's create a new row with new name and the old with old name still there.